# moving datanode from CDH to mapR

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh, mapr

I have 5 node CDH based cluster. In which I have 3 data nodes. 3 zookeeper quorum  running. I have to move one data node alone from CDH to mapR cluster. Which presently has 2 data node only. How can I do this? PLease help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest migration is cluster to cluster using `distcp` ( https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html ).

You can find more information about Migration in this part of the MapR documentation :

- [Migration Guide](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Migration+Guide)

*Note: I am not sure to understand all your comments regarding the number of nodes, using `distcp` and other migration tools,, the data are moved independently of the number of nodes in each cluster*